# reformatting locked drive

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have an old drive I want to reuse. No important data that needs to be recovered, just want to wipe it clean and start anew with it. It is currently locked with BitLocker (used with Vista) and I have no idea what became of the keys, passwords, or anything else that might unlock it. In windows 7, is there a way to unlock this drive so that it may be reused? Again, I could care less what happens to any data left on the drive.

Comment: You should be able to simply format all data on it, and recreate the parition.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia says...

> Contrary to the official name, BitLocker Drive Encryption is a **logical
>   volume** encryption system.

So, you can always delete the partition and create a new one. Use Disk Management from Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Bitlocker is only a layer of encryption on the existing data.

It shouldn't prevent you from simply [formatting it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/format-usb-drive/), and starting from a brand new partition.